# Angle between two lines is wrong

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to get angles between two line.
So I used this code.

---

```
int posX = (ScreenWidth) >> 1;

int posY = (ScreenHeight) >> 1;

double radians, degrees;

radians = atan2f( y - posY , x - posX);

degrees = -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians);

NSLog(@"%f %f",degrees,radians);
```

---

But it doesn't work .
The Log is that: 146.309935 -2.553590

What's the matter?
I can't know the reason.
Please help me.

[image]

Comment: And what about vertical line, does it always vertical?

Comment: I don't know the values of `x`, `y`, `ScreenWidth` and `ScreenHeight`, but this seems correct, other than the fact you're changing the sign of the value in degrees. What result were you expecting?

Comment: I want to get angle between the y-axis and the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you simply use

```
radians = atan2f( y - posY , x - posX);
```

you'll get the angle with the horizontal line `y=posY` (blue angle).

[image]

You'll need to add `M_PI_2` to your radians value to get the correct result.

Comment: Please explain in more detail.

Comment: I edited your image. You are calculating the blue angle instead of the red one.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a function I use. It works great for me...

```
float cartesianAngle(float x, float y) {
    float a = atanf(y / (x ? x : 0.0000001));
    if      (x > 0 && y > 0) a += 0;
    else if (x < 0 && y > 0) a += M_PI;
    else if (x < 0 && y < 0) a += M_PI;
    else if (x > 0 && y < 0) a += M_PI * 2;
    return a;
}
```

**EDIT:** After some research I found out you can just use **[atan2(y,x)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)**. Most compiler libraries have this function. You can ignore my function above.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 points and want to calculate an angle between them here is a quick and correct way of calculating the right angle value:

```
double AngleBetweenThreePoints(CGPoint pointA, CGPoint pointB, CGPoint pointC)
{
    CGFloat a = pointB.x - pointA.x;
    CGFloat b = pointB.y - pointA.y;
    CGFloat c = pointB.x - pointC.x;
    CGFloat d = pointB.y - pointC.y;

    CGFloat atanA = atan2(a, b);
    CGFloat atanB = atan2(c, d);

    return atanB - atanA;
}
```

This will work for you if you specify point on one of the lines, intersection point and point on the other line.

Comment: Shouldn't those calls to `atan2()` specify `atan2(Δy, Δx)`, and thus `atan2(b, a)` and `atan2(d, c)`?