# How to calculate angle between two Geographical/GPS coordinates?

Tags: gps, coordinates, latitude-longitude, angle

I have two GPS Coordinates

e.g. (Lat1, Long1) and (Lat2,Long2)

Could anybody please help me find the angle between those two points.

Values should be 0-360 degrees.

Comment: Is this homework? If yes, please tag it as `homework`.

Answer (score 10):

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809179/angle-between-2-gps-coordinates) previous SO post:

```
float dy = lat2 - lat1;
float dx = cosf(M_PI/180*lat1)*(long2 - long1);
float angle = atan2f(dy, dx);
```

Comment: What are `M_PI` and `atan2f`?

Comment: @CF84: Please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231466/whats-the-difference-between-pi-and-m-pi-in-objc) link for `M_PI`. For `atan2f` please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418353/angle-between-two-lines-is-wrong).

Comment: @FaCoffee `M_PI` is a **pi**. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mathematical-Constants.html  `atan2f` is a `arc tangent of y/x`, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/atan2

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you mean the bearing to and not the angle between the locations: If (lat1,long1) is stored in a `Location` object `loc1` and (lat2,long2) is stored in `loc2` you get the bearing from loc1 to loc2 like this:

```
float bearing = loc1.bearingTo(loc2);
```

The result is in degrees east of true north and its the initial bearing (which is important if loc1 and loc2 are far apart from each other).

There are some other useful methods in the `Location` class, see here for more details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

EDIT: I assumed Android for the answer, but yes, the tags do not imply that ...

Comment: That's fine if he is on Android, but the tags don't say he is.