# What's the difference between "pi" and "M_PI" in objc

Tags: objective-c, math, pi

Including some math in my code I stumbled over the constant "PI".
At least in my Xcode version 4.6 I could use either one. But what is the difference between `pi` and `M_PI`? The documentation is  little bit tight on that topic.

Comment: `pi` isn't a standard constant in Cocoa headers I have included, nor is `PI`. `M_PI` is the standard definition from math.h, and should be fine for most purposes.

Comment: @BenZotto: `M_PI` is a posix-ism, not part of the C standard.

Comment: @StephenCanon: Right. I meant "standard" as in "the one everyone uses". :)

Comment: M_PI is close enough to approximate the circumference of the galaxy (and probably the whole Universe) within a few miles, so I wouldn't lose sleep over it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`pi` is defined in the "CarbonCore.framework" headers as

```
extern const double_t pi  __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __MAC_10_8, __IPHONE_NA, __IPHONE_NA);
```

but marked as "deprecated". I assume that it is a relict from older Carbon frameworks.

`M_PI` is defined as a macro

```
#define M_PI   3.14159265358979323846264338327950288
```

in [`math.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/math.h.html)
and part of the POSIX standard.

The values are identical, but you should use `M_PI` for portability reasons.

(And for *Swift,* see [How to get mathemical PI constant in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324050/how-to-get-mathemical-pi-constant-in-swift.))

Comment: Thanks for the answer and WOW! That is good to know to not use `pi` (I always did so far). Can I straight include `M_PI` in my code or do I need to `#import...` a special class as well.

Comment: If you already import the Foundation or CoreFoundation headers then you can just use it, because these include `<math.h>`. Otherwise you have to add `#include <math.h>` to your code.