# How to get mathemical PI constant in Swift

Tags: swift, math, darwin

I am trying to find a way to *include the PI constant in my Swift code*. I already found help in another answer, to `import Darwin` which I know gives me access to *C functions*.

I also checked the `Math` package  in `Darwin` and came across the following declaration:

`var M_PI: Double { get } /* pi             */`

So, I assume there is a way to use PI in the code, I just don't know *how*...

Answer (score 308, accepted):

With **Swift 3 & 4**, pi is now defined as a static variable on the floating point number types `Double`, `Float` and `CGFloat`, so no specific imports are required any more:

```
Double.pi
Float.pi
CGFloat.pi
```

Also note that the actual type of `.pi` can be inferred by the compiler. So, in situations where it's clear from the context that you are using e.g. `CGFloat`, you can just use `.pi` (thanks to @Qbyte and @rickster for pointing that out in the comments).

For **older versions of Swift**:

`M_PI` is originally defined in `Darwin` but is also contained in `Foundation` and `UIKit`, so importing any of these will give you the right access.

```
import Darwin // or Foundation or UIKit

let pi = M_PI
```

**Note:**
As noted in the comments, pi can also be used as *unicode* character in Swift, so you might as well do

```
let π = M_PI
```

`alt + p` is the shortcut (on US-keyboards) that will create the `π` unicode character.

Comment: As Swift supports Unicode, you could also do `var π = M_PI`

Comment: As pi is a constant, it seems perverse to declare it as a `var`. Surely `let pi = M_PI`?

Comment: @Cyrille sounds kinda cool but wouldn't that mean copy-paste every time we want to reference it?

Comment: Don't know about the standard keyboard, but on my custom keyboard mapping (made with Ukulele) that's simple as typing alt+P, along with a slew of other custom characters.

Comment: You don't need anything special - Alt-p is pi by default.

Comment: Alt-P on an US keyboard, I assume? Definitely not on mine (where it invokes print window). Please, please, don't write random unicode characters in code. I don't want my colleagues to go googling how to write π everytime they find it in code.

Comment: you don't need to `import Darwin` to get `M_PI`

Comment: well, `M_PI` is in the package `Darwin`, **but** it is also in `UIKit`. so you don't get it for free, but you need to import either `UIKit` or at the very least `Darwin` to use it.

Comment: It's not the Alt key, it's the Option key. It's Option-P! </rant>

Comment: :D well, the `option` key is **labelled** with `alt`, so I guess it's fair to say that `alt + p` is the requested shortcut ;) @GaryMakin

Comment: Just a note: If the type of Pi can be inferred you can also use `.pi` instead of the long form. E.g. `let x = CGFloat(42) * .pi`

Comment: +1 to @Qbyte's comment. Type inference is the "big idea" behind making `.pi` a static member of *all* the floating point types: if you're calling an API that takes a floating point value, you can just pass (or do math with) `.pi` and not have to care which type; e.g. `maxMarker.center = CGPoint(x: .pi / 2, y: 1)`

Comment: But what about the precomputed constants M_PI_2, M_PI_4? Should we define them for each floating type? They were really useful in programs doing a lot of geometry stuff!

Comment: @Sulthan You're typing command-P.  The alt/option key is the middle one, between the command and control keys.  If you have an Apple-manufactured keyboard, it should be prominently labelled “option” with a smaller “alt” label.

Answer (score 15):

`import Darwin` is not needed all M_x are visible with the `import Foundation`

( Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b) )

Answer (score 4):

warning: 'M_PI' is deprecated: Please use 'Double.pi' or '.pi' to get the value of correct type and avoid casting.

surprisingly, .pi also works fine. 
M_PI is deprecated as of Swift 4.2.1, Xcode 10.1, which is the current version I am using. SO, Use .pi, or Double.pi