# Cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type '($9 floatLiteralConvertible)'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Getting an error- Cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type '($9 floatLiteralConvertible)'

```
let π = 22.0/7.0

func degreesToRadians() -> Int 
{
  let selfCGFloat:CGFloat = CGFloat( π ) * CGFloat( self ) / 180.0
  return Int(selfCGFloat)
}
```

Comment: What is the type of self ?

Comment: Why do you declare π as 22.0/7.0? That's only a rough approximation of PI. You should be using `let π = M_PI` and `import darwin` before that line. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324050/how-to-get-mathemical-pi-constant-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with:

```
CGFloat( self )
```

The `self` probably not an instance of class that can be converted to `float`.

Change that code with any actual value, everything will work perfectly:

```
let selfCGFloat:CGFloat = CGFloat( π ) * CGFloat( 70.0 ) / 180.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the `180` to CGFloat:

```
CGFloat(180.0)
```

Comment: What is the value of self?