# How to break up this expression into distinct sub-expressions?

Tags: swift, swift3

> Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider
>   breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

```
public func SKTTimingFunctionExtremeBackEaseInOut(t: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
  if t < 0.5 {
    let f = 2.0 * t
    return 0.5 * (f * f - sin(f * π)) * f
  } else {
    let f = 2.0 * (1.0 - t)
    return 1.0 - 0.5 * (f * f - sin(f * π)) * f
  }
}
```

> return 1.0 - 0.5 * (f * f - sin(f * π)) * f

This line caused the crash. It error after I update to swift 3. How would I rewrite it?

Comment: How did you define `π` ?

Comment: Did you define `π`? [Relevant Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26324067/335858)

Comment: I defined π in CGFloatExtensions with let π = CGFloat(M_PI)

Comment: With that definition I cannot reproduce the problem, and your code compiles without problems.

Comment: Is your platform 32 or 64-bit? CGFloat has the same width as your platform