# What is M_PI/Double.pi used for, and why do we use it? Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I am using swift spritekit.

Hi, I have a couple of questions about M_PI, which I recently learnt about. For my game, I have been researching different ways to rotate things. Basically, in my game there are 2 planes "flying" around the center of the screen.

NOTE: When I tried to use M_PI Xcode warned me to use double.pi, which I used to replace M_PI. Are these things the same thing?

1. I tried to work out how to rotate a plane around the centre of the screen. I found out that the best way to do that was to make that a child to a centre node and then rotate the centre node, using this line of code:

   ```
       let OrbitCenter = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(-2 * Double.pi), duration: 3.8)
   ```

   When I took away the Double.pi, the planes moved a lot slower but still 
   rotated in the same way. Why do we need to use Double.pi?
2. I wanted one of the planes/SKSpriteNodes to be upside down, so I researched and found this: `PlaneBlue.zRotation = CGFloat(16.0)`. Again, when I take away the `Double.pi`, it has the same effect however it is just pointing somewhere else.

Overall, my two questions are, is Double.pi the same as M_PI, but just Double.pi is the new way of using this or are they different. Also, why do we need to use Double.pi/M_PI?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For `M_PI` vs `Double.pi` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324050/how-to-get-mathemical-pi-constant-in-swift.

Comment: Thank you, but are the both 'macros'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Double.pi` is used in this sample because `rotate(byAngle:duration:)` takes an angle in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian). 2π radians is equal to one full rotation, or 360 degrees. The code you included is creating a rotation action telling the plane to rotate one full rotation every 3.8 seconds. Removing the `Double.pi` is just causing it to rotate a smaller angle every 3.8 seconds.

As for the difference between `M_PI` and `Double.pi`, they're basically the same. The latter is newer and matches similar constants on other types, such as `CGFloat.pi`. These other constants allow you to get correctly-typed values of π for other numeric types. `M_PI` was always a `Double`, but `CGFloat.pi` is a `CGFloat`, `Float.pi` is a `Float`, etc.

In fact, in your code, switching to `CGFloat.pi` *might* allow you to remove the `CGFloat` cast around your angle parameter, like so:

`let OrbitCenter = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: -2 * CGFloat.pi, duration: 3.8)`

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language. no need to specify the `.pi` type `let orbitCenter = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: -2 *.pi, duration: 3.8)`

Comment: BTW it Swift is convention to name your vars starting with a lowercase letter

Comment: Unless you're using something without inference. Then you'll get a `ambiguous use of 'pi'` error. Sometimes you need `CGFloat.pi` etc.