# What's the difference between M_PI and M_PI_2?

Tags: swift

I forked a project from Github, Xcode shows a lot of warnings:

> 'M_PI' is deprecated: Please use 'Double.pi' or '.pi' to get the value
>   of correct type and avoid casting.

and

> 'M_PI_2' is deprecated: Please use 'Double.pi' or '.pi' to get the value
>   of correct type and avoid casting.

Since both `M_PI` and `M_PI_2` are prompted to be replaced by `Double.pi`, I assume there are in fact the same value. However, there's this code in the project:

```
switch angle {

    case M_PI_2:
        ...

    case M_PI:
        ...

    case Double.pi * 3:
        ...

    default:
        ...

}
```

I'm really confused here, are `M_PI` and `M_PI_2` different? or are they just the same?

**UPDATE:**

It turns out to be my blunder, Xcode says 'M_PI_2' is deprecated: Please use `Double.pi / 2` or `.pi / 2` to get the value of correct type and avoid casting. so it isn't a bug, just too hard to notice the difference of 2 prompts.

Comment: The actual warning for `M_PI_2` is *Please use 'Double.pi / 2' or '.pi / 2' to get the value of correct type and avoid casting.*

Comment: @vadian yeah I just noticed that

Comment: And if you command-click on `M_PI` or `M_PI_2` then you'll find their definition and see that they are different.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `Double.pi / 2` for M_PI_2 and `Double.pi` for M_PI.

You can also use `Float.pi` and `CGFloat.pi`.

In Swift 3 & 4, pi is defined as a static variable on the floating point number types `Double`, `Float` and `CGFloat`.

Comment: I'm just here to copy and paste for the 10th time. 

Answer (score 0):

M_PI is defined as a macro

```
#define M_PI   3.14159265358979323846264338327950288
```

in math.h and part of the POSIX standard.

Follow This
[You can find reference answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231466/whats-the-difference-between-pi-and-m-pi-in-objc)

[Check This Solution - How you can use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324050/how-to-get-mathemical-pi-constant-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

These constants are related to the implementations of different functions in the math library:

```
s_cacos.c:  __real__ res = (double) M_PI_2 - __real__ y;
s_cacosf.c:  __real__ res = (float) M_PI_2 - __real__ y;
s_cacosh.c:                    ? M_PI - M_PI_4 : M_PI_4)
...
s_clogf.c:      __imag__ result = signbit (__real__ x) ? M_PI : 0.0;
```

M_PI, M_PI_2, and M_PI_4 show up quite often but there's no 2.0 * M_PI. 2π is just not that useful, at least in implementing libm.

M_PI_2 and M_PI_4, their existences are well justified. The documentation of the GNU C library suggests that "these constants come from the Unix98 standard and were also available in 4.4BSD". Compilers were not that smart back at that time. Typing M_PI/4 instead of M_PI_4 may cause an unnecessary division. Although modern compilers can optimize that away (GCC uses mpfr since 2008 so even rounding is done correctly), using numeric constants is still a more portable way to write high-performance code.